# how to get focus according to tab order in textview

Tags: android

hi i have the following xml layout

```
     <Button android:id="@+id/signupButton"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "10px"
        android:layout_marginTop = "10px"
        android:text="Sign-Up"/>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/accountlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text = "Forgot password"
    android:textColor = "#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "10px"
    android:layout_marginTop = "10px"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingLeft="3px"
    android:paddingRight="3px"
/>     

 <Button 
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "10px"
            android:layout_marginTop = "10px"
            android:text="SignOut"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

my problem is that focus only goes to one button to another.it doesn't go to textview because my text is  clickable so i need focus on it as well.

i read few solutions like android:focusable = "true" adding in textview but it didnt work.

Someone have any solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to make the TextView into a Button with an empty background by adding the property:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

to the XML. So your TextView would become:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/accountlabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text = "Forgot password"
    android:textColor = "#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "10px"
    android:layout_marginTop = "10px"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingLeft="3px"
    android:paddingRight="3px"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

You could also use an ImageButton if you want to use a selector for different states to add some feedback for the user when the object has focus.

In that case, instead of setting the background to transparent, you could make an XML file with a selector for different states and reference that for the background. See [ImageButton reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

just put
android:clickable="true" in your tect view..

put id of your textview,
and retrieve that id at android size and apply onclick event...

may be this is work foe you...

Comment: i added android:clickable="true" and got event of it in setOnClickListener . Actually when i figured it out my focus goes to textview but it does not show up in UI . As button become orange when in focus but textview does not change any color so we think focus is not there on textview.

Comment: Is there a way to find when texview has got focus and change its background color so that it reflects on UI so that one can eaisly recognize  textview has got focus.

Comment: @Rishi just considor now textview as button now in class coding textview can applyable like button